Feedback session in Enfield
I've been invited out to the LEGO US HQ in Enfield this Friday to talk about Bricks.SE. The event is described as a "Meet and Greet", so it's fairly low-key. I will be giving a brief 10 minute presentation on our community and there will be a feedback session regarding current and future support for us and other fan communities like us.
This post is mostly an FYI, but if there's anything in particular you'd like me to bring up, just let me know.

Wow, that sounds fantastic! I hope you have a good time, it sounds like a good opportunity to meet some interesting people. I can't think of any particular questions at the moment but I'm sure you'll have plenty to talk about.
